# Loss given default for Agency MBS

Tags: models

The question is regarding the LGD of Agency MBS. Although Agencies never defaulted, the Basel framework requires to calculate the Agency MBS LGD for capital requirement. The closest benchmark I can think of is to take the LGD of non agency Prime RMBS as a proxy. Can anyone think of any other benchmark?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they did, in 2008.   On October 6, 2008 ISDA held a credit default auction with Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac as Reference Entities that defaulted.  The senior securities settled at about 91.5 and 94 respectively, if memory serves.  Hence there was very little loss given default.

Answer (score 1):

**Agency** mortgages are very different as they are written to different origination guidelines controlled by agencies. **Non agency prime** MBS comes close to it but they can have different profiles as mostly these are high balance loans that didnt satisfy conforming limits for agency programs.

These days, fannie mae as well as freddie mac release loan level data that can help model defaults as well as severity. for example, i am linking to freddie mae data set.

http://www.freddiemac.com/research/datasets/sf_loanlevel_dataset.page

You should try these data sets now.